# How to get the Web Page names of Website in Dropdownlist and Contents in RichTextBox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, file-io, fckeditor

I want to display all the webpage names (.aspx) which resides in application root directory and display it in DropdownList. According to selection of page the contents of .aspx page must be shown in RichTextBox or some FCKEditor textbox and to save the page contents after editing.

Plz Suggest me the right method!

Help Appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this from MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("/"), "*.aspx");

foreach (string currentFile in files)
{
  string fileName = Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
}
// Add filename to drop down list etc....
```